# How do I find the length/number of items present for an array?

Tags: c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [length of array in function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269048/length-of-array-in-function-argument)

My array size is 5. For example:

```
arrCustId[5]
```

How can I know how many Customer IDs are already present in my array?
In short how to find length of array?

Answer (score 27):

If the array is statically allocated, use `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`

If it's dynamically allocated, though, unfortunately you're out of luck as this trick will always return `sizeof(pointer_type)/sizeof(array[0])` (which will be 4 on a 32 bit system with char*s) You could either a) keep a #define (or const) constant, or b) keep a variable, however.

Comment: If it’s dynamically allocated, it will return `sizeof(pointer) / sizeof(array[0])`.

Answer (score 13):

Do you mean how long is the array itself, or how many customerids are in it?

Because the answer to the first question is easy: 5 (or if you don't want to hard-code it, Ben Stott's answer).

But the answer to the other question cannot be automatically determined. Presumably you have allocated an array of length 5, but will initially have 0 customer IDs in there, and will put them in one at a time, and your question is, "how many customer IDs have I put into the array?"

C can't tell you this. You will need to keep a separate variable, `int numCustIds` (for example). Every time you put a customer ID into the array, increment that variable. Then you can tell how many you have put in.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. If you want to know how many customers there are, just remember how many you put in there.

Answer (score -6):

I'm not sure that i know exactly what you mean.

But to get the length of an initialized array,

doesn't strlen(string) work ??

Comment: strlen is used only on strings because it looks in the initialized array for the NULL terminator (\0).  So it should only be used with char * since they are kinda special.

Comment: well, you sorta right :) but do realize that a string is actually an array of characters...

Comment: But is there a `\0` in other types of arrays?