# How to declare array size with a parameter in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters

Im writing a function in c and here is my code:

```
char* makeMoves(char oldBoard[], int moveType, int empties, char player){
    int oldBoardLength;
    oldBoardLength = sizeof(oldBoard) / sizeof(oldBoard[0]);
    char result[oldBoardLength];
    copyBoard(oldBoard, result);
}
```

I think that this line has a problem:

```
char result[oldBoardLength];
```

how can i create this array with length=oldBoardLength?
In java is something like this:

```
char[] result = new char[oldBoard.length];
```

but in c i don;t know how to create this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post the code where you call `makeMoves`.

Comment: `sizeof(oldBoard) / sizeof(oldBoard[0])` isn't doing what you think it is. `oldBoard` is a pointer in this function; not an array.

Comment: i have not finish the program yet, so i dont call the function makeMoves. I want to take the length of the array. i think that i have the full size of array(bit size) and i divide this with one cell of the array. So i get the length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you have to allocate dynamic storage in such cases.

```
char *result = malloc(oldBoardLength);
copyBoard(oldBoard, result);
free(result);
```

However, you have to pass oldBoardLength into the function, because an argument like `arr[]` or `arr[8]` will always decay to a pointer. Taking `sizeof` on a pointer is not what you have intended. Have a look at the output of this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COUNT_OF(x) ((sizeof(x)/sizeof(0[x])) / ((size_t)(!(sizeof(x) % sizeof(0[x])))))

long int test(char array[16]) {
        return COUNT_OF(array);
}

void main(void) {
        char a[16];
        printf("%ld\n", COUNT_OF(a));  // prints 16
        printf("%ld\n", test(a));      // prints 8 or 4 for 64bit or 32bit systems
}
```

Comment: don't cast the result of malloc in c.

Comment: @2trill2spill as you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

First I would use `char *oldBoard` instead of `char oldBoard[]` There the same but I think `char *oldBoard` is clearer. Second you don't wan't to use `sizeof` as that will not return the correct length, you would just get the size of a pointer. `sizeof(oldBoard) / sizeof(oldBoard[0]);` only works on statically allocated arrays or at least that is what this says [How do I find the length/number of items present for an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604838/how-to-find-array-length-in-c) . Use a another variable to keep track of the array length. Finally use dynamic allocation aka `malloc()` so that the values don't become garbage when you pass them between functions. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do but here is a example of what I think your trying to do.

```
char *makeMoves(char *oldBoard, int len, int moveType, int empties, char player)
{
    char *result;

    result = malloc(len);
    if(result == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    copyBoard(oldBoard, result);

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{

    char *board, *result;
    int len = 10;
    int moveType, empties;
    char player;

    board = malloc(len);
    if(board == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    result = makeMoves(board, len, moveType, empties, player);
    if(result == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    free(board);
    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, the most often used idiom is passing the expected number of elements your pointer parameter points to as a separate parameter. Should be something like this:

```
char* makeMoves(char *oldBoard, int oldBoardLength, int moveType, int empties, char player) {
    /* ... */
}
```

This way, the caller of your function is repsonsible for passing in the correct length.